# How do you send a email on apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, force.com

I found a code for sending email from apex. The problem is it have a part i do not want. If i remove below part it wont work. Any idea how to remove below part.

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Send an Email to Your {!account.name} Representatives">
    <p>Fill out the fields below to test how you might send an email to a user.</p><br />
        <apex:dataTable value="{!account.AccountTeamMembers}" var="contact" border="1">
            <apex:column ><apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>{!contact.user.Name}</apex:column>
            <apex:column ><apex:facet name="header">Email</apex:facet>{!contact.user.Email}</apex:column>
        </apex:dataTable>
        <apex:commandButton value="Send Email" action="{!send}" /> 
</apex:pageBlock>
```

I only want this button. When user click on Send button it should send a email to the sales team.

```
 <apex:pageblockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton value="Send Email" action="{!send}"/> 
 </apex:pageblockButtons>
```

**Extension**

```
    public class gibco {

    public Product_Brief__c pb {get;set;}
    public User u {get;set;}

    private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get;set;}
    public boolean bUpdate {get;set;}
    public string loggedinUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    public User u2 = [Select ContactId From User where Id =: '005R0000001Y6h4'];

    public String ctId{
        get{     
            ctId = u2.ContactId;
            return ctId;
        }
        set;
    }

    Contact ct = [SELECT AccountId, Name FROM Contact WHERE id=:ctId];
    Account acname = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE id=:ct.AccountId];
    public string getacct(){
        Account acct = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE id=:ct.AccountId];  
        return acct.Name;
        return null;
        }

    Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId=:ct.AccountId LIMIT 1];

 /* ********************* Email ************************* */

    public String subject { get; set; }
    public String body { get; set; }
    private Account account;

    public Account getAccount() {
    account = [select Name, (SELECT user.Name, user.email from AccountTeamMembers) 
                from Account where id = :ct.AccountId];
        return account;
    }

    public PageReference send() {
        // Define the email
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 

    String addresses;
    if (account.AccountTeamMembers[0].user.Email != null)
    {
        addresses = account.AccountTeamMembers[0].user.Email;
        // Loop through the whole list of contacts and their emails
        for (Integer i = 1; i < account.AccountTeamMembers.size(); i++) 
        {
            if (account.AccountTeamMembers[i].user.Email != null)
            {
                addresses += ':' + account.AccountTeamMembers[i].user.Email;
            }
        }
    }

        String[] toAddresses = addresses.split(':', 0);

        // Sets the paramaters of the email
        email.setSubject( 'New Media/Buffer Product Brief from '  + ct.Name + ' at ' + acname.Name);
        email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
        String htmlBody= 'Dear ' + ct.Name + ':<br/><br/>';
                htmlBody += 'This is a reminder that your review of ' + ct.Name + ' for the position of ' + 
                    ct.Name + ' has not been completed yet. Please complete this review as soon as possible.' +
                    '<br/><br/>Review Link: <a href=https://cs2.salesforce.com/' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') + '>click here</a><br/><br/>Thank You,<br/>Recruiting Dept.';
                email.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);

        // Sends the email
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});   

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Messaging.SingleEmailMessage to create an email.
For send use Messaging.SendEmail method.
Remember, you can send up to 100 mails in a single Messaging.SendEmail method.

**UPD:** I don't know why my code is so bad formatted.

**Page:**

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account" extensions="AccountExtension"> 

    <apex:form>  
        <apex:pageBlock>  
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>  
                <apex:commandButton value="Send Email" action="{!send}"/>  
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>  
        </apex:pageBlock>  
    </apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

**Extension:**

```
public class AccountExtension {
    public Id acctId;

    public AccountExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        acctId = controller.getRecord().id;
    }

    public PageReference send() {
        List<Id> listUsersId = getListIdsOfAccountTeamMembers();
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = createMails(listUsersId);
        Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
        return null;
    }

    private List<Id> getListIdsOfAccountTeamMembers() {

        List<AccountTeamMember> listAcctTeamMembers = [SELECT Id, UserId FROM AccountTeamMember WHERE AccountId = :acctId];
        return extractUserIdsFromAcctTeamMembers(listAcctTeamMembers);
    }

    private List<Id> extractUserIdsFromAcctTeamMembers(List<AccountTeamMember> listAcctTM) {
        List<Id> result = new List<Id> ();
        for (AccountTeamMember tempAcctTM : listAcctTM) {
            result.add(tempAcctTM.UserId);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> createMails(List<Id> listIds) {
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> result = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> ();
        for (Id userId : listIds) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setTargetObjectId(userId);
            mail.setSubject('New mail');
            mail.setUseSignature(false);  
            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);  
            mail.setHtmlBody('<h1>Some text using HTML tags</h1>');  
            result.add(mail);  
        }return result;
}  
}
```